# React Collapsible - Add an icon

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React-Collapsible like this :

```
<Collapsible trigger="Fiche de référencement"  >
<h2>Hello world</h2>
</Collapsible >
```

I want to put an icon wit the text "Fiche de référencement", but I don't know how can I do that ? 
Can you help me ? 
Thank you

Comment: An icon with the text "Fiche de réferencement"? You mean you want to pass it an icon? Can you clarify?

Comment: The parameter trigger enables to have a title of each accordion. I want also a chevron icon, but the parameter trigger just recognizes a text, and not icon and image... So I would want to know if there is a solution ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to pass an icon to this thing. What you can do is look at what it returns, https://github.com/glennflanagan/react-collapsible/blob/develop/src/Collapsible.js#L248

In any case, this is handled by the span element with the class `Collapsible__trigger`. Information on it can be found in the example here: https://github.com/glennflanagan/react-collapsible/blob/develop/example/_src/sass/components/_Collapsible.scss#L37

Comment: Thank you but can you give me an example please ?

Comment: What I mean is that there is nothing you can pass in with the way this library does it. In the last link I gave you, line 37 is where they set the content for the icon. It's handled with text '\f107'.  For some sort of image, you would do something like this in css `content: url(image.jpg);`

Comment: Ok, I understand, I see what you mean, good idea ! thank you !

Comment: Cool. @AnaïsSaez Mark it as a solution. It gives me points and points make me a winner.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example-

```
import { BsChevronDown } from "react-icons/bs"; //react-icon
.
.
<Collapsible trigger={["Serial No.", <BsChevronDown />]}>
  <div/> //children
</Collapsible>
```

Css-

```
.Collapsible__trigger {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.Collapsible__trigger.is-open svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<Collapsible trigger={[Fiche de référencement, <Icon name="remove"]}  >

### Hello world

```js
<Collapsible trigger="Fiche de référencement"  >
<h2>Hello world</h2>
</Collapsible >
```